# Moving rows by one in Hibernate or MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Let's suppose I have a table with some rows:

```
id   |   order_id
1    |       1
2    |       2
3    |       3
4    |       4
5    |       5
...  |       ...
...  |       ...
99   |       99
100  |       100
```

what is the best way to move rows in a table? for e.g. I want to move 2 between 99 and 100, so 99 and others will move -1 row and 2 will be 99. This example is for 100 rows, but there can be thousands of rows as well, maybe there is a more efficient way.

Comment: You can try something similar to linked list insertion, no need to move all the rows. Update(swap) only the order_id & use that column in order by clause while fetching, don't know exactly if it meets your requirements.